# WPF Xaml StringFormat issue

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, telerik, string-formatting

I'm binding a property to a GridViewDataColumn, and I want to add a string format :

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Points, StringFormat='{0} point(s)'}"/>
```

The problem is that the line is underlined, and I don't know why.

On this [link](http://www.e-naxos.com/Blog/post/StringFormat-une-simplification-Xaml-trop-peu-utilisee.aspx), the author do the same code like me.

What is my error ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Telerik components, but could you try this:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Points, StringFormat={}{0} point(s)}"/>
```